# Make this flutter page scrollable

Tags: flutter, dart

The code below, is the main page of my app. When I want to make a new icon/button, it's only could make up to 4, if I make it to 5 or more, the 5th button that I make is not showing up in my app which showing text "bottom overflowed" [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZvFb.png)

so how to make this page scrollable? and here is my code on this main page.

```
import 'package:bacaan_sholat/page/bacaan_sholat_page.dart';
import 'package:bacaan_sholat/page/niat_sholat_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
 const MainPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     backgroundColor: Colors.green.shade100,
     body: SafeArea(
       child: Center(
         child: Column(
           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
           children: [
             Container(
               margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
               child: Expanded(
                 child: InkWell(
                   highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                   splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                   onTap: () {
                     Navigator.push(
                         context,
                         MaterialPageRoute(
                             builder: (context) => NiatSholat()));
                   },
                   child: Column(
                     children: [
                       Image(
                         image: AssetImage("assets/images/ic_niat.png"),
                         height: 100,
                         width: 100,
                       ),
                       SizedBox(height: 10),
                       Text(
                         "Doa Harian Muslim",
                         style: TextStyle(
                             fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                       ),
                     ],
                   ),
                 ),
               ),
             ),
             SizedBox(height: 40),
             Container(
               margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
               child: Expanded(
                 child: InkWell(
                   highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                   splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                   onTap: () {
                     Navigator.push(
                         context,
                         MaterialPageRoute(
                             builder: (context) => BacaanSholat()));
                   },
                   child: Column(
                     children: [
                       Image(
                         image: AssetImage("assets/images/ic_doa.png"),
                         height: 100,
                         width: 100,
                       ),
                       SizedBox(height: 10),
                       Text(
                         "Bacaan Sholat",
                         style: TextStyle(
                             fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                       ),
                     ],
                   ),
                 ),
               ),
             ),
             SizedBox(height: 40),
             Container(
               margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
               child: Expanded(
                 child: InkWell(
                   highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                   splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                   onTap: () {
                     Navigator.push(context,
                         MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AyatKursi()));
                   },
                   child: Column(
                     children: [
                       Image(
                         image: AssetImage("assets/images/ic_bacaan.png"),
                         height: 100,
                         width: 100,
                       ),
                       SizedBox(height: 10),
                       Text(
                         "Ayat Kursi",
                         style: TextStyle(
                             fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                       ),
                     ],
                   ),
                 ),
               ),
             ),
             SizedBox(height: 40),
             Container(
               margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
               child: Expanded(
                 child: InkWell(
                   highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                   splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                   onTap: () {
                     Navigator.push(
                         context,
                         MaterialPageRoute(
                             builder: (context) => BacaanSholat()));
                   },
                   child: Column(
                     children: [
                       Image(
                         image: AssetImage("assets/images/ic_doa.png"),
                         height: 100,
                         width: 100,
                       ),
                       SizedBox(height: 10),
                       Text(
                         "Bacaan Sholat",
                         style: TextStyle(
                             fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                       ),
                     ],
                   ),
                 ),
               ),
             ),
             SizedBox(height: 40),
             Container(
               margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
               child: Expanded(
                 child: InkWell(
                   highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                   splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                   onTap: () {
                     Navigator.push(
                         context,
                         MaterialPageRoute(
                             builder: (context) => BacaanSholat()));
                   },
                   child: Column(
                     children: [
                       Image(
                         image: AssetImage("assets/images/ic_doa.png"),
                         height: 100,
                         width: 100,
                       ),
                       SizedBox(height: 10),
                       Text(
                         "Bacaan Sholat",
                         style: TextStyle(
                             fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                       ),
                     ],
                   ),
                 ),
               ),
             ),
           ],
         ),
       ),
     ),
   );
 }
}
```

Any help or advice is really helpful and meaningful for me and thanks in advance. I'm sorry if this question quite messy 'cause this is my first question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it with `SingleChildScrollView` and that's pretty much it!

```
...
body: SafeArea(
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
...
```

**Note:** Since you are using `SingleChildScrollView` the `MainAxisAlignment.center` will make no changes so consider removing that.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `Column` widget with `SingleChildScrollView` so rest of your content will scrollable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).